# Canva and Polotno responsive page

Tags: html, css, fabricjs

I built a web app like Canva and Polotno using FabricJs .... but i stuck on a problem related to responsive

[polotno editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy647.png)

In Polotno, the canvas page always fits the user device size (width & height) by scaling; with some calculations the output is the zoom percentage needed to fit the page... I don't need to change width and height, I just need to scale the canvas

```
    var zoomPercentage = 100;

    function updateZoom() { 
        $('#canvas-pages').css('transform','scale(' + (zoomPercentage / 100) + ')');
        $('#zoom-precent').val(zoomPercentage);
        console.log(zoomPercentage);
    }

    function calculateZoom() {
        var containerWidth = $('#page-container').width(); 
        var containerContent = $('#canvas-pages').width(); 
        zoomPercentage = (containerWidth / containerContent ) * 100; 
        updateZoom();
    }

    window.onresize = calculateZoom;
```